# CloudRun private service to service hostnames

Tags: google-cloud-run

When making east-west service to service calls on CloudRun the documentation covers [service to service authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) but the example doesn't include any documentation on the correct way to address internal services.

There is the cloud run deploy generated url but it includes mystery randomness `https://{service}-{a google id?}.a.run.app` meaning you can't do east-west calls using just the service name like you can in a GKE cluster.

I'm wondering if I've just missed the documentation in CloudRun or upstream in the Knative serving docs or I need to implement some sort of service discovery using the CloudRun HTTP or RPC APIs?

Comment: What do you mean by "east-west" service to service calls?

Comment: In regards to service to service authentication, the example is correct, you just need to understand OAuth service account credentials and how to verify the tokens. A good example is needed to show how. This article might help you: https://medium.com/@stephen.darling/oauth2-authentication-with-google-cloud-run-700015a092c2

Comment: In regards to internal services - what services are you referring to? In some cases, a service has automatic authentication verification based upon headers sent to Cloud Run, which Cloud Run verifies behind the scenes for you.

Comment: In regards to service discovery, that does not exist with Cloud Run. If you want known endpoint names, you can create your own endpoint URLs in your DNS server. Cloud Run is designed more towards an HTTP request/response framework. Think microservices, web services, etc and not closely coupled services as in Kubernetes. Another comparison is Cloud Functions but on steroids.

Comment: East-west is microservice speak for in network/cluster service to service communication. You'll find it used a lot in service mesh products like Istio that Knative uses by default.

Comment: My question is what do you mean by east-west service to service in regards to Cloud Run? Istio, service mesh, etc do not apply to Cloud Run. Cloud Run for Kubernetes is different.

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm hoping someone who works on Cloud Run could clarify exactly how close the products are. I've answered my own question in the meantime though, Cloud Run doesn't provide convenient service hostnames as Cloud Run on GKE does for service to service traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Run (the managed service) does not provide the same name quality of life hostnames that Cloud Run on GKE or Kubernetes in general does. `{service}` or `{service}.{namespace}.srv.cluster.local` etc will not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the new runsd project. It solves DNS service discovery for Cloud Run by giving you friendly hostnames to call other Cloud Run services that are in the same project. It also automatically authenticates every request that goes to a Cloud Run service

https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-service-discovery/